# Find and sort in O(n) the log2(n) smallest values and the log2(n) largest values in an array of n values

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures, heapsort

Let A be an array of n different numbers (positive & negative).

We are interested in the `⌊log_2(n)⌋` smallest values,

and in the `⌊log_2(n)⌋` largest values.

Find algorithm which calculates this `2⌊log_2(n)⌋` values,

and presents them in a sorted array (`size = 2⌊log_2(n)⌋`)

```
1. the running time of the algorithm must be θ(n),
2. prove that the running time is θ(n).
```

I thought maybe heap sort can be useful, but I'm really not sure.

I don't need a code just the idea... I would appreciate any help

Thanks :) and sorry if I have English mistakes :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My general approach would be to to create 2 heap data structures, one for the max and one for the min, and heapify the array for/in in both of them. Heapifying is an operation of linear time complexity if done right.

Then I would extract `⌊log_2(n)⌋` items from both heaps where each extraction is of complexity `O(log n)`. So, this would give us the following rough estimation of calculations:

```
2 * n + 2 * (log(n))^2
```

`2 * n` for two heapifying operations.
`log(n) * log(n)` for extracting `log(n)` elements from one of the heaps.
`2 * (log(n))^2` for extracting `log(n)` elements from both heaps.

In big O terms, the ruling term is `n`, since `log(n)` even to the power of two is asymptotically smaller. So the whole expression above renders to a sweet `O(n)`.

Comment: wow thanks! can you explain why log(n) * log(n) for extracting log(n) elements?
and why not using only one heap and extract the values?

Comment: In a heap each extraction or addition is a logarithmic operation and since you are extracting log(n) elements this becomes `log(n) * log(n)`. If you use only one heap, you have to extract all the element to get both the minimum and maximum values. This is n operations times log(n) complexity each which is the same as sortings `n * log n`. In essence, the idea is to sort only the parts we care about and leave the rest alone.

Comment: can you look at: [link](https://ibb.co/7JXXNTB)
In this min-heap, I need to extract the 4 smallest elements (1,2,3,4). but the complexity is more than `log(n) * log(n)` no?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that a properly implemented heap has `log (n)` extraction/insertion complexity and lets you peek at the tip of the heap in `O(1)`. Please note that unlike a BST, you can't binary search in a heap for arbitrary values. Searching the heap is linear. Heaps only guarantee that each node is greater/smaller than its direct children, nothing more. When extracting, the tip is swapped with a leaf, the leaf is removed and the new tip is sunk into the tree while swapping with the right nodes to guarantee the heap invariant.

Comment: Have a look at this https://www.cs.umd.edu/~meesh/351/mount/lectures/lect12-heaps-and-heapsort.pdf and the following lectures about how heap works. Also, look at this https://github.com/williamfiset/Algorithms/blob/master/src/main/java/com/williamfiset/algorithms/datastructures/priorityqueue/BinaryHeap.java for a concrete implementation and ideas.

Comment: In a previous comment, with `the right nodes to guarantee...`, I mean `the correct nodes (right or left)...`. Right means correct here not the direction, but I'm sure you already understood that :D

Comment: ohh ok I got it :0 thank you my friend!